# Clojurescript libraries - goog.require could not find

Tags: leiningen, clojurescript, cljsbuild

New to clojurescript, and working through the "Modern CLJS" tutorial [here](https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/).

It instructs to pull in [domina](https://github.com/levand/domina) by adding it to the `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
               [compojure "1.1.5"]
               [domina "1.0.0"]]
```

And then use it in your script by referencing it in the `ns` form

```
(ns cljstut.login
  (:use [domina :only [by-id value]]))
```

However, when I actually run this in a browser, I see the following in the console log.

```
goog.require could not find: domina
```

Seems like I'm missing some declaration somewhere? But as a newb, this whole build process is rather opaque. Any troubleshooting tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Dependencies in your `project.clj` file and your namespace declarations look fine.

If you are building your clojurescript code using `lein cljsbuild auto`, you will need to restart that process. I believe it should automatically pull in new dependencies after a restart.

If that doesn't work, or you aren't using `lein cljsbuild auto`, try running the `lein deps` command inside your project's folder manually - it will fetch all missing dependencies from remote repositories.

Comment: I've actually just gotten through this, and I think it may have been domina 1.0.1 that fixed it? Something about goog-jar or something was a dependency in 1.0.0 and it no longer takes that. Does that seems reasonable?

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I believe with `domina 1.0.0` you had to add an explicit dependency on the google clojure third party lib in order to make things work.

Comment: Restarting `lein cljsbuild auto` worked for me for a similar error.

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure you have saved your `project.clj` file and try running `lein clean` and `lein cljsbuild clean`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the process of updating modern-cljs to the latest versions of the used libs and lein plugins. At the moment I updated the series up to the 7th tutorial of the series. You should now be safe by updating to domina 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT into project.cljs :dependencies and to lein-cljsbuild 0.3.0 into project.cljs :plugins.

Mimmo

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that a typo in the namespace would trigger the same error message:

> goog.require could not find: domina

Example (note the missing "j" in modern-cljs):

```
(ns modern-cls.login
  (:use [domina :only [by-id value]]))
```

I was using a different project name thus a different namespace just to be brave.
It bit me in the ass when I copy-pasted from the guide and the error had me puzzled for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue while working through the "Modern CLJS" tutorial. My problem was inadvertently adding the "domina" dependency to the :plugins section of project.clj rather than the :dependencies section.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this error message by putting lines in the right order in the index.html file.

Correct order:

```
<script src="js/expanding_gases.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">goog.require("expanding_gases.flow_gases");</script>
```

Incorrect order:

```
<script type="text/javascript">goog.require("expanding_gases.flow_gases");</script>
<script src="js/expanding_gases.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By the way a good read for understanding 'goog' messages is here:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start